# Error using cv2.findContours(), with python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I've recently started learning OpenCV on Python.

I'm referring to [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) tutorial here, to get some help on getting the contours of an image.

My code is -

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('shapes.jpg', 0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)
thresh =     cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

cv2.imshow('Thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

image, contours, hierarchy =   cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(image, countours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('Contours', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The first thresholded image is appearing, but after that I get an error message as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "contours.py", line 21, in <module>
    image, contours, hierarchy =     cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

Any help to resolve this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Look at [this](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/70440/cv2.findContours) example.

```
cv2.findContours(...)
```

only returns two objects, you're trying to unpack it into three.

change that line to this:

```
contours, hierarchy =   cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

and it should work.

Comment: Depending on Opencv version, findContours can have 2 or 3 return values...

Comment: Hey @will, do you mind updating your answer based for latest version too? You could save us some time.

Answer (score 11):

The tutorial you have linked is for `OpenCV version 3`. `cv2.findContours` does return 3 objects in that version.

So either update opencv or use the solution by @will .

Comment: Did not realize this. Nice catch.

Comment: I realized this pretty late.

Comment: What are those three objects? Links to docs would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

In version `4.1.2-dev` it returns only two values.
You have to unpack it with two values and then use `cv2.drawContours()` to see them.
This is the link to the documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html